# Quartz API error

Tags: java, exception, quartz-scheduler

When I compile and run my application on my local machine with specs Windows XP sp2, JDK 5u11, I get no error. But when I try to run this application (compiled on Windows XP) on a Linux Debian distro, JDK 5 I get the following error:

```
Unable to instantiate class load helper class: null
```

What can I do to get rid of this exception message?

Comment: Without a full stacktrace, some code (the part where you instantiate the `StdSchedulerFactory`), it seems hard to say anything. Please provide some details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this isn't really enough info to help, but a simple Google search led me to the source code which explalins it a bit:

Quartz has a "ClassLoadHelper" interface and you can specify the class name of the implementation of this to use. You've not configured it, or there's an error in creating it. Perhaps it's complaining it doesn't have the name of a class to instantiate.

In any event the code apparently logs a stack trace with this, so you should provide that.

Comment: you are right, but the stack tree will be displayed if i able to catch exception, it catches exception but not giving its message or stack print